# How do I find out the version pigenhole installed

Tags: 14.04, versions, dovecot

So I installed [pigeonhole](http://pigeonhole.dovecot.org/) with

```
apt-get install dovecot-managesieved dovecot-sieve
```

But it looks to me that behaviour is different from documented. I think that might be because ubuntu source version lags behind. How do I check what version of pigeonhole is installed on my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [dovecot mailing list](https://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2016-January/102970.html):

> Pigeonhole releases are not always bound to a specific Dovecot release
>   (nearby versions usually also work). Release announcements contain the
>   Dovecot version they were released with. Pigeonhole version numbers
>   alone do not provide this information though.
>
> Newer Pigeonhole releases add a version line to the dovecot -n output
>   and they log the version at startup when mail_debug is enabled.
>
> Version history is as follows:

```
dovecot-2.2-pigeonhole$ git log --grep="^Released" --oneline
9d7b172 Released v0.4.11 for Dovecot v2.2.21.
439ad92 Released v0.4.11.rc1 for Dovecot v2.2.21.
fa008c0 Released v0.4.10 for Dovecot v2.2.21.
543848b Released v0.4.10.rc2 for Dovecot v2.2.20.
c3af27f Released v0.4.10.rc1 for Dovecot v2.2.20.rc1.
cef2176 Released v0.4.9 for Dovecot v2.2.19.
df7e58f Released v0.4.9.rc1 for Dovecot v2.2.19.rc1.
f95a87c Released v0.4.8 for Dovecot v2.2.18.
6f5be00 Released v0.4.8.rc3 for Dovecot v2.2.17.
42fe82a Released v0.4.8.rc2 for Dovecot v2.2.17.rc1.
c6c9320 Released v0.4.8.rc1 for Dovecot v2.2.17.rc1.
1052e9e Released v0.4.7 for Dovecot v2.2.16.
3103de6 Released v0.4.7.rc3 for Dovecot v2.2.16.
5acb35f Released v0.4.7.rc2 for Dovecot v2.2.16.
b63e87a Released v0.4.7.rc1 for Dovecot v2.2.16.rc1.
a06cc4b Released v0.4.6 for Dovecot v2.2.15.
890ae8e Released v0.4.5 for Dovecot v2.2.15.
cc57bb2 Released v0.4.4 for Dovecot v2.2.15.
84dde15 Released v0.4.3 for Dovecot v2.2.13.
1d85222 Released v0.3.6 for Dovecot v2.1.17.
a080843 Released v0.4.2 for Dovecot v2.2.6.
3ae0c2b Released v0.4.1 for Dovecot v2.2.4.
9791b4a Released v0.4.0 for Dovecot v2.2.1.
46755a8 Released v0.3.5 for Dovecot v2.1.16.
173e9dd Released v0.3.4 for Dovecot v2.1.16.
4ad40fc Released v0.3.3 for Dovecot v2.1.10.
0102b7f Released v0.3.2 for Dovecot v2.1.9.
28ac609 Released v0.3.1 for Dovecot v2.1.6.
eb0b1b2 Released v0.3.0 for Dovecot v2.1.0.
335451a Released v0.2.5 for Dovecot v2.0.16.
ba82a8f Released v0.2.4 for Dovecot v2.0.14.
1ef3f05 Released v0.2.3 for Dovecot v2.0.12.
c70867f Released v0.2.2 for Dovecot v2.0.8.
5d3a336 Released v0.2.1 for Dovecot v2.0.4.
7202ebb Released v0.2.0 for Dovecot v2.0.2.
798f218 Released v0.1.5 for Dovecot v1.2.rc3.
1dd42d5 Released v0.1.4 for Dovecot v1.2.beta3.
d6e7b70 Released v0.1.3 for Dovecot v1.2.beta1.
cf2ad5b Released v0.1.2 for Dovecot v1.2.alpha4.
bd9e1b2 Released v0.1.1 for Dovecot v1.2.alpha4.
f7270d1 Released v0.1.0 for Dovecot v1.2.alpha3.
```

For reference, the source code git is [here](https://github.com/dovecot/pigeonhole).

Answer (score 1):

Simply run in terminal:

```
apt-cache policy NAME-OF-PACKAGE
```

or with help of `dpkg`

```
dpkg -l | grep NAME-OF-PACKAGE
```

Comment: Unfortunately these commands give the dovecot version (2.2.9) not the pigeonhole version that I'm interested in.

Comment: these commands show the version of package installed. Is your package named `pigeonhole` itself?

Comment: "not the pigeonhole version that I'm interested in" What version are you *interested* in? @zespri

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish: no it's not. I'm sorry I could not be more clear but I both provided the link to the product in the question as well as the command line that I used to install the product. The current version of pigeonhole is 0.4.3. In ubuntu it's bundled as two packages dovecot-managesieved and dovecot-sieve. Both of these have the same version as dovecot.

Comment: Also note, that all I want is to find out the version, I suspect there is no way to do it with console commands if the ubuntu packaging process strips it out, but surely there should be some other way to find it? There probably logs somewhere which version of components ubuntu packages are built from?

Comment: @Lucio: the pigeonhole version, as per the pigeonhole web page linked in the question. Cheers.

Comment: @zespri there's no package `pigeonhole` within Ubuntu repos that exists, what you get is `dovecot`, other questions about project versions should be addressed to developer/maintainer of the project.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I do agree that this is a difficult question, so don't feel bad about not knowing the answer. May be someone else who has more knowledge about how ubuntu packages are build could chime in and clear things up. Thank you again for you interest. Your reply *was* useful in that it provoked some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This post is very old, but I cannot see an direct answer, but I answer:

With "***doveconf***" command, first lines show "*pigeonhole*" version:

```
$ doveconf | head
# 2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.21 (92477967)
...
```